# python 3.8/3.9 IDLE won't run

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, python-idle

Yesterday my IDLE stopped working after I have tried to run

```
print(datetime.datetime)
```

I could open my IDLE and from there go to File>Open and open a .py file, but I couldn't right click on a .py file and open it with IDLE.

I have added the PATH again, reinstalled python, added python 3.9.

Now when I click on IDLE 3.8 or 3.9 I doesn't do anything. If I want to open a .py file with IDLE, it doesn't do nothing.

I have read 5 similar topics around here but neither one solved this problem.

Any thoughts?

Can't even run it on VScode, gives the following error

```
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

Package        Version

---

DateTime       4.3
numpy          1.19.3
opencv-python  4.5.1.48
pip            21.0.1
pytz           2021.1
setuptools     49.2.1
XlsxWriter     1.3.7
zope.interface 5.2.0

Comment: When you are already in idle and open the open-file dialog you just need to double-click the file.

Comment: "Now when I click on IDLE 3.8 or 3.9 I doesn't do anything." I can't open de IDLE.

Comment: Is this referencing the very first step of opening IDLE, or when you are inside of and trying to open a file. If it's the former I'd advise to just start over. probably less headaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have uninstalled and deleted all the remaining python folders from AppData and Program Files and also uninstalled Anaconda3.

Freshly installed 3.9 and now I can open the IDLE and from it go to File>Open.

It's kinda' sad I can't use to "Edit with IDLE" anymore, but at least now the IDLE works(somehow).